# Take value from table using didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to get a value from a table view controller and send it to another table view controller.

I want to achieve it through the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` where I have used

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];  
NSString *num=cell.textLabel.text;
```

The problem here is that the cell contains a number and a string but I only want the number.
Is there a way to get only the number?

Comment: How is the number put into the cell?  You'd be better off getting it from the "dataSource" than trying to read it back from a cell.

Comment: Is the text a certain format? Then you could use [num substringWithRange:NSMakeRange()] or maybe make an array of it by using [oldTimezone componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].

Comment: im inserting the data with: cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d   %@",vc.Number,vc.Address]; As a result my table has one number and one address in each cell. When i press a specific cell i need to take only the number of that specific cell. But NSString *num=cell.textLabel.text returns both number and address together

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Instead of trying to extract it from the textlabel, set the cell's tag value to the number in cellForRowAtIndexPath method and use it in the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.tag = vc.Number;
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];  
NSUInteger num=cell.tag;
```

Answer (score 4):

There's almost no reason I can think of where trying to store information about your data inside labels or tags of your views is a good idea. It makes the program harder to write and harder to understand. Instead, use the same methods that provided the data to put in the view in the first place. Here's an example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id dataObject = [self dataForIndexPath:indexPath]; // assuming you called this in ..cellForRow... to provide the "vc" instance you mentioned in your comment
    int value = dataObject.number;
    //Now go do work with the value you extracted. 
}
```

This method `dataForIndexPath:` just represents the work done to get the `vc` instance you referred to in your comment as being the source for the data used to populate table cell's  label. Notice that this method doesn't access the views at all - it goes right to the original source of the data to get exactly what you need. Unlike the other solution, this will also work for data of any type, not just integers.

Hope this helps, and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: +1. The proliferation of tags to store state is an abomination.